# k8s is not creating a new pv/persistent mount mount per pod in same node when using the same volumeHandle name. using csi-s3

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

the problem I am trying to solve is allowing each pod to have its own PV/PVC/Secret for each mount in its namespace.

when a csi-s3 has the same volumeHandle(used to define the bucket name) k8s will allow another pod to access that PV and not create a unique PV(another csi-s3 fuse mount in this case) on the node. This is using readWriteMany, and the secret, pv and pvc are different at the metadata name level

the error message I see with ReadWriteOnce on PVC/PV

```
  Warning  FailedAttachVolume      83s   attachdetach-controller  Multi-Attach error for volume "usr-user-3-username001-0-6-1-00000003-462-3-csi-storage" Volume is already used by pod(s) podname-454-3-a, podname-455-3-a, podname-458-3-a
```